# CORS slim framework. Angular request to apache not working

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, cors, slim

I have a chorme plugin that allows me to toggle CORS by inserting a header. If I use that my slim code works. If not then I get an error as follows.

> (index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost/api/flowers. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

My code

> $app = new \Slim\Slim();
>   $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
>   $app->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',>
>   'Content-Type');
>   $app->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT,
>   POST, DELETE');
>   $app->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
>
> $app->get('/', function() use($app){
>
> $ins = new Lead();
>   $products = $ins->run();
>   echo
>   json_encode($products);
>             });

If I use the crome extension then the header response from the server is as follows.

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 23:04:26 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
>   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
>   Connection: Keep-Alive Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type:
>   application/json

So the headers are being sent. But CORS still does not work without the extension. I need to fix this for all browsers of course. Not just mine. I'm pretty sure its a small mistake but I'm not seing it. What's wrong here?

Comment: localhost:9000 is nodejs. localhost:8080 is apache

Answer (score 1):

Your system needs to handle "options" routes.

Browsers use an OPTIONS request at the same URL. So essentially you need to handle 2 requests.

If you add in a $app->options("/:name+"); it should fix it.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's a catch all route. Some browsers send a pre-flight OPTIONS request to ensure that the browser is actually able to request the resource in question. You must attach the CORS headers to this OPTION request and the response of the actual resource.